# replace text in input tag if they already exist in array

Tags: html, jquery

I have array with set of values and one of the value is untitled, and a input tag with default value as untitled so onclick of submit the input tag value should be changed to untitled1 since untitled already exist in array(so if untitled1 also exist in array the input tag value should change to untitled2)

```
arr=['untitled','val1','val2']
```

```
<input type="text" id="sub-proj"  placeholder="Project Name" maxlength="50" required="required" value="untitled"/>
<button type="submit" id="form-done" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitfun()">Done</button>
```

```
submitfun(){
if(arr.includes('untitled')){
       document.getElementById("sub-proj").value = "untitled1"
       arr.push('untitled1')
     }
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything from your end, can you please share it with us?

Comment: yes updated the code.what I have tried only works for one condition,next time untitled1 will also be added to arr.hence onclick of submit input text value should change to untitled2.@BhushanKawadkar

Comment: Keep track of your current untitled iteration, and change the if statement to include the current iteration. Like `untitledIter = ''` then `if (arr.includes(`untitled${untitledIter}`)` and increment every time you find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of below logic where you can use `count` variable to keep track of number with `untitled` value and replace value after every click and push it to the array.

```js
var arr=['untitled','val1','val2'];
var count = 1;
function submitfun(){
var value = document.getElementById("sub-proj").value;
   if(arr.includes(value)){
       value = "untitled" + count;
       arr.push(value);
       document.getElementById("sub-proj").value = value;
       count++;
     }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sub-proj"  placeholder="Project Name" maxlength="50" required="required" value="untitled"/>
<button type="submit" id="form-done" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitfun()">Done</button>
```